# How do I install Ubuntu onto my USB drive?

Tags: installation, usb

I ran Ubuntu from a LiveUSB.  I would like to *actually* install Ubuntu on my usb drive while I am running Ubuntu from the USB live. When I ran the installer (by clicking the "install" icon on the live desktop), it wouldn't let me select my usb drive.

How do I actually install Ubuntu onto my usb drive?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm adding this answer because it does explain one of the OP's original questions, which was "can I do this?" I'm explaining why he can't.*

The reason you can't select it is because the USB is mounted, and you can't partition mounted devices. So to install Ubuntu on it like you're trying to do, you'd need another USB to boot from, so the original USB can be left unmounted.

If you would like to install onto a USB drive, check out [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)